# Windows Phone Unit Test App associated with won't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-8

You cannot vote on your own post 
0

Hello Everyone,

> note: this has been posted on the Windows Phone MSND forum on which I
>   was adviced to ask the same question on the Live Connect SDK
>   forums...that are now on stackoverflow.

I'd like to use some Unit Tests to automatically verfiy my usage of the Live SDK to access One Drive.
It seams that for the LiveSDK to be able to connect to the services the app has to be associated to the store.

For the record I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 application.

Unfortunately a Windows Phone Unit Test App that has been associated to the store does not seem to work. This is what I see in the Visual Studio output:

```
========== Discover test finished: 1 found (0:00:00,4120231) ==========
------ Run test started ------
Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
Creating a new clean layout...
Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
Registering the application to run from layout...
Deployment complete (2666ms). Full package name: "MyTestApp_1.1.0.0_x86__v05mkgjvmsq4a"
The application is not installed.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:03,3748925) ==========
```

Has someone already managed to use the LiveSDK within unit tests? If yes, would you please so kind to share how you achieved that?

Any piece of idea to get that working will be appreciated !

Many thanks in advance,

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you want to unit test a foreign SDK? You should mock the SDK and verify that you call if correctly and react correctly for predefined results.

My goal is here not to test the Live Connect SDK but my usage of it. And by usage I mean the real one not against a mock: I'd like to verify that my code works well with the real SDK.

Of course to actually test my own classes I do have a mock of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but it had nothing to do with the Live SDK (as I'm not using it).

Ultimately I added a new Unit Test (Windows Phone 8.1) project, and brought all my tests over to it, removing the old one.  I couldn't figure out how to fix it otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to unit test a foreign SDK? You should mock the SDK and verify that you call if correctly and react correctly for predefined results.

I guess you are also not testing the other Microsoft Phone SDKs :-)